# JQuery Animations Form Outline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a login form, and whenever someone will click the input, I want to animate it by adding an outline. When using jquery, I tried different methods, and I could get the animation on, but I couldn't get it off. I want the animation to come off when someone clicks elsewhere. I have tried using the * selector but that came to no avail. The following is the structure of my code :

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans|Roboto+Condensed');
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
body {
    background: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTkvMfKjaJCpaOFlBZwHp2EuQobP9J9Ejuvgyvls8UvxRsmk2vqWA') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
.login-cont {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.input-cont {
    border: none;
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 35px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
}
.log-input {
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    height: 70px;
    width: 325px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
    font-weight: normal;

}
.inp-ali1 {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 22.5px 0;
    height: 25px;
}
.inp-ali2 {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin: 23.5px 0;
    height: 25px;
}
}
.col-centered {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin: 25px auto;
}
.log-title {
    font-family: "Fira Sans";
}
.wb {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Fira Sans";
}
.smt-btn {
    border-radius: 10px;

}
a:link {
    font-size: 15px;
}
.inp-act {
    outline: deeppink solid 3px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 549px) {
    .login-cont {
        background-color: white;
        margin-left: 3%;
        margin-right: 3%;
        border-radius: 0.75%;
        width: inherit;
    }
}
```

```html
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"><head>
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="login-cont col-centered text-center navbar-form">
<br>
<br>
        <h1 class="log-title">LOGIN</h1>
        <br>
        <form action="/Home.html">
        <div class="input-cont">
            <span class="stay"><label><i class="fa fa-envelope-o inp-ali1" aria-hidden="true"></i><input  type="email" class="log-input" placeholder="Email" required>
            </label></span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-cont">
           <span class="stay"><label><i class="fa fa-lock inp-ali2" aria-hidden="true"></i><input type="password" class="log-input" placeholder="Password" required></label></span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <span><label for="remember"><input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="remember"></label></span>
        <br>
        <button class="smt-btn btn">Submit</button> 
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a> <br>
        <a href="#">New? Register.</a>
        <br>
        </form>
    </div>
```

So, I have an inp-act class that is to be added to the container div of the login inputs, and that is what I would like to be used. My end goal is to have when one clicks on the input, the outline will show up, and when one clicks out, it will disappear.

Comment: If you didn't realize, I am using jquery 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery [focusin()](https://api.jquery.com/focusin/) and [focusout()](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/).

On focus, add the `inp-act` class to `.input-cont` using [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). When focus is removed, remove the class.

```js
var input = $('.log-input');

input.each(function() {
  $(this).focusin(function() {
    $(this).closest('.input-cont').addClass('inp-act');
  });
  $(this).focusout(function() {
    $(this).closest('.input-cont').removeClass('inp-act');
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans|Roboto+Condensed');
textarea:focus,
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTkvMfKjaJCpaOFlBZwHp2EuQobP9J9Ejuvgyvls8UvxRsmk2vqWA') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
  .login-cont {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .input-cont {
    border: none;
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 35px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
  }
  .log-input {
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    height: 70px;
    width: 325px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  .inp-ali1 {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 22.5px 0;
    height: 25px;
  }
  .inp-ali2 {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin: 23.5px 0;
    height: 25px;
  }
}

.col-centered {
  float: none;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

.log-title {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
}

.wb {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
}

.smt-btn {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

a:link {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.log-input {
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.inp-act {
  outline: 3px solid purple;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 549px) {
  .login-cont {
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    border-radius: 0.75%;
    width: inherit;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <head>
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="login-cont col-centered text-center navbar-form">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1 class="log-title">LOGIN</h1>
        <br>
        <form action="/Home.html">
          <div class="input-cont">
            <span class="stay"><label><i class="fa fa-envelope-o inp-ali1" aria-hidden="true"></i><input  type="email" class="log-input" placeholder="Email" required>
            </label></span>
          </div>
          <div class="input-cont">
            <span class="stay"><label><i class="fa fa-lock inp-ali2" aria-hidden="true"></i><input type="password" class="log-input" placeholder="Password" required></label></span>
          </div>
          <br>
          <span><label for="remember"><input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="remember"></label></span>
          <br>
          <button class="smt-btn btn">Submit</button>
          <br>
          <br>
          <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a> <br>
          <a href="#">New? Register.</a>
          <br>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: this is close to what I want, but I want it to affect the closest '.input-cont' which is the part that I have been struggling with

Comment: @NermalSkywalker Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Writing out my idea without testing, I usually use some kind of class toggle that removes classes of all inactive items, and appends the 'active' class to the focused element. In this case it might look something like this:

```
$('.input-cont').on('click', function() {
    $('.input-cont').removeClass('input-active');
    $(this).addClass('input-active');
});
```

`.input-active` will have all your styles of the focused input which you now can animate in.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this correctly, this could be achieved with simple CSS `:focus`

```
textarea,input{
    outline:none;
}
textarea:focus,input:focus{
    outline: #000000 dotted thick;
}
```

Or if you want it to actually animate, you could use `transition` on `border-width` or something like that, kinda like this:

```
textarea,input{
    border: 0px solid red;
    transition: border-width 0.25s linear;
}
textarea:focus,input:focus{
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

Note: I did not test any of this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however this would not work as I am not trying to change the input itself, but the div that contains the input.